# how to manage/organize layouts in android studio when number of layouts in the project are too large?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Normally when I create an android project I try to separate android java or kotlin files in packages as per their functions like activity, fragments, adapters, etc.

[Image for package distribution of kotlin files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muI2O.png)

Now as my project size is increasing thus the number of layouts files. At present I have around 20 layout files and it is difficult to know which file is linked to what when I refer project again after few weeks. I want to know if there is a better way to organize layout files just like as I did for kotlin files in the structure of cards, activities, fragments, etc.
I found the package option to organize the kotlin files clicking right clicking, so I tried the same and there I found the option folder, But when I place file in that folder android studio isn't detecting it.
So is there a better way to organize these layout files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found just one way of doing it and that is by appending the particular layout name by type name.

For example, if we have a card layout file and dialog layout file, then it helps if we name them as **card_(File name)** and **dialog_(File name)**.